# How to merge two data row warning off power and on power into one in Oracle 10g, 11g , MySQL , SQL SERVER (no support MATCH RECOGNIZE )

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yakmTD5M2MEINdBEg2ckUTb3vw7YPFTO/view?usp=sharing

Hi everybody,

I have said the given problem with the linked link link and be resolve with SQL solution for Pattern Matching is supported or ORACLE 12C by Wernfried Domscheit's with information :

```
CREATE TABLE ALERT_EVENT (MEASUREMENT_POINT VARCHAR2(10), TIME_ALERT DATE, STATUS VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('04/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('03/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('02/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE01', to_date('01/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('03/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF'); 
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('02/10/2018 23:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE02',  to_date('02/10/2018 22:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03', to_date('04/10/2018 10:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('02/10/2018 23:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('02/10/2018 22:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER OFF');
INSERT INTO ALERT_EVENT VALUES('PE03',  to_date('01/10/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'POWER ON');
```

Query Result use ORACLE Matching Pattern
    You are quite close, try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALERT_EVENT ml
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     PARTITION BY MEASUREMENT_POINT
     ORDER BY TIME_ALERT
     MEASURES  STRT.TIME_ALERT AS start_tstamp,
               LAST(END.TIME_ALERT) AS end_tstamp
     PATTERN (STRT END*)
     DEFINE
        STRT AS STRT.STATUS LIKE '%OFF%' ,
        END AS END.STATUS LIKE '%ON%' 
     ) MR
ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_POINT ,start_tstamp;

MEASUREMENT_POINT   START_TSTAMP           END_TSTAMP
==================  =====================  ====================
PE01                2018-10-01 00:00:00    2018-10-02 00:00:00
PE01                2018-10-03 00:00:00    2018-10-04 00:00:00
PE02                2018-10-02 22:00:00    2018-10-02 23:00:00
PE02                2018-10-03 00:00:00 
PE03                2018-10-02 22:00:00    2018-10-02 23:00:00
PE03                2018-10-04 10:00:00
```

Problem: But executing to the Oracle older version or MySQL or SQL Server, SQL for Pattern Matching is not supported for this function. Which solution to query the general for the given questions that does not use SQL for Pattern Matching?

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pre-Oracle 12c by creating a new column to group by, then finding the min/max time_alerts for the relevant statuses per the measurement point and the new grouping column.

The grouping column is generated by calculating a running sum and increasing it by 1 every time it encounters a POWER OFF status.

That gives us a query something along the lines of:

```
select measurement_point,
       min(case when status = 'POWER OFF' then time_alert end) start_tstamp,
       max(case when status = 'POWER ON' then time_alert end) end_tstamp
from   (select measurement_point,
               time_alert,
               status,
               sum(case when status = 'POWER OFF' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by measurement_point order by time_alert) grp
        from   alert_event)
group by measurement_point, grp
having min(case when status = 'POWER OFF' then time_alert end) is not null
order by measurement_point, min(time_alert);

MEASUREMENT_POINT START_TSTAMP        END_TSTAMP
----------------- ------------------- -------------------
PE01              01/10/2018 00:00:00 02/10/2018 00:00:00
PE01              03/10/2018 00:00:00 04/10/2018 00:00:00
PE02              02/10/2018 22:00:00 02/10/2018 23:00:00
PE02              03/10/2018 00:00:00 
PE03              02/10/2018 22:00:00 02/10/2018 23:00:00
PE03              04/10/2018 10:00:00
```

Note that this will group consecutive rows with a status of 'POWER ON' into one group; you will have to play around with how the grp column is generated if that's not what you want.